# Pass and maintain variable value across the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far I have tried this. I want to pass the value of a variable across the scene. How can I maintain the value. I want to get position of a game object from one scene to another but the script re initialized the value of GameObject **v** variable.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Maintainer : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject v;//I want to maintain this value across the scene
public GameObject cameraGO;
static Maintainer instance;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake() {

}

void Start () {

    Debug.Log("awake ");

    if (instance != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Instance not null");
        //Dont want new
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("instance is null");
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = this;
    }
    //DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject.transform);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (cameraGO != null)
    {
        v = cameraGO;
        Debug.Log("camera position " + cameraGO);
    }
    else {
        Debug.LogError("Camera not found!");
    }

    Debug.Log("Camera Position : "+ v);

}

void OnGUI() { 
  if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 150, 100), "Load Scene 2")){
        print("You clicked the button!");
        Application.LoadLevel ("Scene2PassValue");
  }
  if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 150, 150, 100), "Load Scene 1"))
  {
     // Debug.Log("Camera Position : " + v.transform.position);
      print("You clicked the button!");
      Application.LoadLevel("Scene1PassValue");
  }        
}   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the value a static class field?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which value are you trying to pass across, and  is the value something you need to reference in another class?

Comment: @Takarii gameobject v value

Comment: @RonBeyer yeah i have tried

Comment: Is it `Maintainer` that you want to keep? Setting `instance = this` does not save a "copy", its just a reference, so when the `this` class gets disposed, so does the `instance`. What *specific* data do you want to save across instances?

Comment: @RonBeyer gameobject v value i want to maintain across the scene

Comment: @RonBeyer I want to get the position of one gameobject into other scene

Comment: OK, did you try making the `GameObject` static, instead of the entire instance?

Comment: try setting up a get/set method - `public GameObject myV {get {return v;} set {v = value;}` then you can access the variable from another class using myObject.myV

Answer (score 0):

All tough it is not to clear what you tried exactly, I can see you tried to use the `DontDestroyOnLoad`. This would be the correct way to keep your Script to persist through out the several scenes. There is but a tiny mistake in the usage. And that is the application in the `start()`.

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any of the Update methods is called the first time.

Instead of using it in the start, you will want to use it in the `awake()` instead.

> Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded.

Just to make sure, before you call the `DontDestroyOnLoad` you could also set the `transform.parent = null` to prevent deletion from other sources. This off course is only the case if it is a child of a object.

And don't forget to re-work this logic. Whenever you load a new scene, the start will be triggered again iirc. Which would mean that on the scene load, if you saved your previous object, you would destroy it again.

```
// If we do not have a instance yet
if (instance == null)
{
    Debug.Log("Instance null");
    instance = this;
}
```

Comment: i added my conditions to awake function but problem still persist while i want to maintain the position of gameobject v across the scene